# Problem file binary in read/write with tfilestream

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Hello I need to work with very big binary files so i can't use functions such as Assign(), Closefile() etc. I want to use TFileStream for its Read()/Write() methods. But I have problem because I can't read back what I've written to the stream. I have understood that the problem was related to the encoding so I think I need to use Unicode and not Ansi. But I haven't understood how to do it. Can someone help me, with examples ? I know how to write/read from/to a file but this doesn't help me solve the problem.

Comment: `TFileStream` works with raw data (bytes), not strings, so your `Ansi` vs `Unicode` problem is by no means obvious or usual. You should include some code with your question.

Comment: Open your `TFileStream` with `fmOpenReadWrite` or `fmCreate` and you can read as well as write. You also need to seek. Since you didn't give any code then it's hard to say more.

Answer (score 3):

If you control both writing and reading, you can use readers and writers. For example:

```
var
  reader : TReader;
begin
  reader := TReader.Create(MyStream, BufferSize);
  try
    myString : = reader.ReadString;

  finally
    reader.Free;
  end;
end;
```

TReader has a way to distinguish between unicode and ansistring as long as they are written by TWriter.

If you don't controll the write part. You hopefully have a way to know the file format. (At least the strings and their size). So you can prepare a buffer to read the characters in.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my answer was wrong, just like Andreas said. Maybe this post is going to help you?
[Writing a string to a TFileStream in Delphi 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434413/writing-a-string-to-a-tfilestream-in-delphi-2010)

Comment: -1. Apparently you missed the first sentence of the Q: "i can't use function as Assign, Closefile etc". Also, you missed the title of the Q: "... **tfilestream** ".

Answer (score -1):

If you want to write/read strings from/to a stream, the easy way is to cast your string as a Shortstring which is always 255 char long (but it implies that your string must not be longer than 255 chars). If you only need to read/write strings in your streams then use a TStringList instead.

Otherwise you have other more complex options:

- write/ read a TStringList into the stream ( then you have to implement a kind of file format)
- write the string and to retrieve it read char by char and accumulate chars until a null char is encountered, repeat the operation for each string

Comment: -1 for suggesting `ShortString`: way too many limitations associated with it to be used as a solution to this problem. +1 for suggesting `TStringList`. -1 for "kind of file format" with `TStringList`, because `TStringList` has `SaveToStream` and `LoadFromStream` methods, not to mention `SaveToFile` and `LoadFromFile`. -1 for suggesting reading and writing to stream char-by-char.

Comment: About the file format: you can save the StringList to a TMemoryStream then you write the MemoryStream.Memory to the main stream. I use this a lot: in the main file you write the stream size then the stream.memory, this for an unlimited number of streams. Interpreting the file format is easy: read upcoming 'streamsize', cast next 'streamsize' bytes as something and so on... About the ShortString: limitations of this method were mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I don't get why you would use a memory stream in between. Why not save the string list directly to the filestream?