# Performance slowdown after porting Delphi 7 application to Delphi 2007

Tags: performance, delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2007

I recently ported a legacy Delphi 7 app to Delphi 2007. My users have been complaining that portions of the application are significantly slower in the new version. I did upgrade to newer versions of Developer Express components in the port, but since then I've reverted back and the slowdown still occurs, so I believe I've eliminated DevExpress as the cause. Other than that, the code is probably at least 98% the same.  What could possibly cause a performance slowdown in D2007? I've been using 2007 for years without any issues like this.

Comment: No way for us to answer that. Could be all sorts of reasons for this. Remember that we cannot see your code and know nothing about your app. Profile your app to find out what the bottleneck is.

Comment: There are no general problems with Delphi 2007 performance that I know of.  But you're working blind until you actually PROFILE your app in a PROFILER.

Answer (score 2):

Use a performance [profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368938/delphi-profiling-tools). SmartBear has a [free](http://smartbear.com/products/free-tools/aqtime-standard) one that's more than capable. There are several other free and commercial profilers out there as well.

Once you find the bottleneck, if its not apparent what's causing it, paste the code into your question and we can try to troubleshoot it.