# Intercept Delphi 2007 Form Creation Process to Time Component Creation

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have a form with a lot of components on it that is taking a LONG time to display.  I have isolated the issue to being before the OnShow gets called so it must be one (or more) of the components on the form taking a long time to create.  Is there a way to hook in to the TForm component creation logic to see what component is causing the issue?

Comment: Think of using a general purpose profiler, will need it anyway.

Comment: Any suggestions for a good one?

Comment: Included aqtime was enough for me, but AFAIR no tools for D2007. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291631/profiler-and-memory-analysis-tools-for-delphi and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368938/delphi-profiling-tools .

Comment: "*I have a form with a lot of components on it*" - then you should consider redesigning your UI.

Comment: "then you should consider redesigning your UI" - much easier said than done.  The UI is standardized across the application and other forms with the same number of components don't have this issue.  It's just this one form.  I think I have isolated the naughty one through trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error I figured out which component it was and determined that it was something to do with the debugger as running the application outside of Delphi had much better performance than from within.