# Application.Restore does not get me to where I was before, why?

Tags: delphi, forms, delphi-2009, restore

The application I am now trying to support ([a former creation of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763464/whats-the-hardest-program-youve-written/763502#763502)) is a complete mess, and so I programmed an extension to it as a separate executable which I then launch, call `application.minimize;` and `WaitForSingleObject` (the recently created process). Right after that I call `application.restore` to get me back to where I left off.

```
application.Minimize;
WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
Application.Restore;
Application.BringToFront;
BringToFront; //the topmost form which was used to launch the app
Show;
```

I can then see (Win XP), how to describe it?, the *frame* of the app jump up from the task bar and do as if the app was restoring itself to screen but it does not actually show. As you can see, I am quite desperate and combined app.restore, app.bringtofront,form.bringtofront,form.show... but I think I need some sort of application.show, activate, focus... can't seem to find those.

Also, why is this not enough?

```
application.Minimize;
WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
Application.Restore;
```

**EDIT**

The main form is `wsMaximized`, this calls `anotherform.showmodal;` which then eventually tries to minimize the app, launch the other process, and restore the app. I think the trick is with the MODALity of the topmost form.

sample code for the other (topmost) form that is shown as modal:

```
function ExecAndWait(const FileName, Params: string;
  WindowState: Word): Boolean;
var
  SUInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcInfo: TProcessInformation;
  CmdLine: string;
begin
  { Enclose filename in quotes to take care of
    long filenames with spaces. }
  CmdLine := '"' + FileName + '" ' + Params;
  FillChar(SUInfo, SizeOf(SUInfo), #0);
  with SUInfo do
  begin
    cb := SizeOf(SUInfo);
    dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    wShowWindow := WindowState;
  end;
  Result := CreateProcess(nil, PChar(CmdLine), nil, nil, False,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil,
    PChar(ExtractFilePath(FileName)),
    SUInfo, ProcInfo);
  { Wait for it to finish. }
  if Result then
  begin
    application.Minimize;
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    Application.Restore;
    Application.BringToFront;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ExecAndWait('C:\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe' , '' , SW_NORMAL);
end;
```

Comment: Just minimize followed by restore works for me. Have you tried Application.ProcessMessages?

Comment: And you have no way to debug?

Comment: Well, the debugger kind of makes it even harder. If I placed a breakpoint there, Delphi would activate itself exactly in the place where I would desire my app to activate. Debugger gets in the way. I am trying running the app without debugger and just trying to find the right command that would actually display the application once it's been restored.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a tiny app and post the code here?

Comment: @Jeroen, I tried and I could reproduce this quite easily. New VCL Forms app, button on the form. New form. button on form1 calls form2.showmodal. Button on form2, this button then calls app.minimize, creates process, app.restore and it doesn't work. Code for form2 is in the question.

Comment: @MasterPeter - I can't reproduce this on WinXp with Delphi5. The mspaint is in Winnt folder. The Application.Minimize doesn't get run until mspaint is closed. If I first minimize the application, then create mspaint, close and restore it, the only "fluke" is see on my second monitor is that the application doesn't minimize at all.

Comment: Perhaps you're bitten by Windows Ghosting as here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsuidevelopment/thread/4cc0426d-571e-4dc2-b51d-7700890fefaf and here http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_23358991.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ShowModal causes all the forms of the application to be disabled, except the modal form. You cannot minimize, restore a disabled window at will. Try sth. like;

```
  if Result then
  begin
    EnableWindow(Application.MainForm.Handle, True);
    application.Minimize;
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    Application.Restore;
    EnableWindow(Application.MainForm.Handle, False);
    Application.BringToFront;
  end;
```

Comment: thanks for an answer, there were too many comments piling up below the question. I'll try this now.

Comment: superb! This did the trick! I didn't know that "ShowModal causes all the forms of the application to be disabled". This is a pretty useful insight. ta

Comment: You're welcome! To prevent a misunderstanding, rather than a cause, ShowModal disables the forms (by calling DisableTaskWindows). Anyway, what is being done here is somewhat against the TApplication design, so you'd be watching for anomaly, for instance if there are more forms.