# Assorted list of what's new in Delphi [Language, RTL, VCL]?

Tags: delphi

As someone who's been stuck at the older versions of Delphi and upgraded to D2010 lately, I figure I still use the language, RTL and VCL features from the D5 era and refrain from using these new features as the documents on those are somewhat decentralized around the blogosphere. So I'd like to ask if there was an assorted list like [what's new docs of Python's](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/index.html) - clear and concise to the point.

Btw, please no screencasts. They seem to be quite abundant lately (probably because of CodeRages) but I find them very unintuitive to learn from. Let's leave that docs in video format thing to RoR community, shall we :).

Comment: See also, "lesser-known language constructs" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280462/lesser-known-language-constructs-of-object-pascal-delphi

Comment: See also "changes from D7 to D2009" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352080/delphi-incremental-changes-from-d7-to-d2009

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no single, centralized list with the changes between versions of Delphi.
Here you have a list of links of changes for each version.

- [What's New in Delphi 6](http://sysdoc.doors.ch/BORLAND/del6_faq.pdf)
- [What's New in Delphi 7](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/images/28980/D7_whats_new.pdf)
- [What's New in Delphi 2005](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32778)
- [What's new in Delphi 2006](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33411)
- [What's New in Delphi 2007](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/36608)
- [What's new in Delphi 2009](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38490)
- [What's new in Delphi 2010](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/whats-new)
- [What's new in Delphi XE](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE)
- [What's new in Delphi XE2](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE2)
- [What's new in Delphi XE3](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE3)
- [What's new in Delphi XE4](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE4)
- [What's new in Delphi XE5](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE5)
- [What's new in Delphi XE6](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE6)
- [What's new in Delphi XE7](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE7)
- [What's new in Delphi XE8](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE8)
- [What's new in Delphi 10 Seattle](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/What%27s_New)

Comment: Thanks for listing all of these.

Answer (score 4):

Class constructors were added in the latest release, but are not listed in the included help, or in the [What's New](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_2010#Delphi_Compiler_Changes) section of the new wiki. Check out Allen Bauer's blog [here](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2009/09/03/38898) for details.

Suspend/Resume for threads are now deprecated, but apparently could have been causing problems for years - see [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread.Suspend). Use the new [Start](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread.Start) method instead.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is online, including this topic: [What's New in Delphi and C++Builder 2010](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_2010).

There's also a pretty good collection of features for versions up to Delph 2009 on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305016/what-are-major-incentives-to-upgrade-to-d2009-unicode-excluded/305262).

Answer (score 2):

The Delphi 2010 help file has a history of new features over the past several versions. See the "What's New" topic, and follow the sub-links from there. That should give you a good overview.

Comment: I wish it went back a little bit more. (it stops at D2007).